# Check android App is installed second time

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Is there a work around to check if the android app installed in the same device for the second time as well as the first installation date .Does `Google Play Services` provides api to fetch details pertaining to apps installation   and uninstallation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311644/get-application-installed-date-on-android
have a look at it

Comment: @UsmanKurd I tried this method before it gives the `firstInstallTime` of the current installation.Though the app was previously installed and removed.

Comment: save some file on the device

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own server and when app installed on mobile, get the `IMEI` code and send to  the server and store it in `database` . if the user again installed that app and when you get `IMEI` code on server compare and check whether `IMEI` exist or not . if exist he is installing again else he is installing for the very `first time`.

Comment: I am looking for a method which doesn't involve having a server.Any idea `google play services` provides a `api` to achieve this.

Comment: You can just store IMEI in the preferences. In OnCreate of main activity check it, if there is no - first start.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't hear about such `Play Services` possabilities. But you can do it like @wqrahd told you or just, with out `server` part, create file on your external storage.

And to check if you are installing or updating application use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). They will not be removed after Application update so you can create some migration scheme and check it, like this :

```
public class MigrationManager {
    private final static String KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION = "key_preferences_version";
    private final static int PREFERENCES_VERSION = 2;

    public static void migrate(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        checkPreferences(preferences);
    }

    private static void checkPreferences(SharedPreferences thePreferences) {
        final double oldVersion = thePreferences.getInt(KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION, 1);

        if (oldVersion < PREFERENCES_VERSION) {
            final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = thePreferences.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putInt(KEY_PREFERENCES_VERSION, currentVersion);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote an [article](http://yakivmospan.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/best-practice-sharedpreferences/) about Preferences where migration scheme is described. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Shared Preferences can solve this problem as if user can **Clear Data** from

> Settings> applications> Manage application>

all data will be lost. Other solutions are needed.